# No Visual Studio Code como configurar para permite indentar código automaticamente?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Encontrei esse site.

https://oraculoti.com.br/2017/07/11/visual-studio-code-permite-indentar-codigo-automaticamente/

porém não encontrei o arquivo.

Encontrei também esse site.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Mas a versão do meu visual code não contempla essa explicação acima, alguém poderia me explicar onde devo configurar o visual code na versão mais atual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vc pode fazer de duas formas, indentando o documento como um todo, ou apenas um bloco selecionado de código.

***Os atalho abaixo funcionam no VS Code para Windows, para os demais OS consultar os links***

- Lista de atalhos no Linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf
- Lista de atalhos no iOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

**Para indentar o documento todo**

Se vc quiser formatar o documento inteiro vc aperta <kbd>Shift+Alt+F</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Para indentar uma seleção feita no bloco de código**

Se vc quiser formatar apenas um bloco de código primeiro vc tem que selecionar ele com o mouse, e depois vc aperta <kbd>Ctrl+K Ctrl+F</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Caso opte por extensões...**

Eu recomendo a **Beautify** que vc pode encontrar no Market Place do VS Code. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

Ou **Prettier** dependendo do código que vc quer formatar... https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode